# model for the movement of a stock price

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A model for the movement of a stock price supposes that if the present price is S then after one period, say one second, it will either go up to uS with probability p or go down to dS with probability q = 1 - p. Assuming that successive movements are independent,approximate the probability that the stock will be up by at least 5% after the next 1000 periods for u = 1.02, d = 0.95 and p = 0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find how many ups and downs are necessary.

Since $1.05^{723} \times 0.98^{277} \approx 1.115$ and  $1.05^{722} \times 0.98^{278} \approx 1.039$, you need at least $723$ upticks, as you have already found.  You need the number of upticks to be to be at least $\dfrac{\log(1.05/0.95^{1000})}{\log(1.02/0.95)}.$

Using the R code `1-pbinom(772,1000,0.6)` this probability is about `2.929176e-16` which is extremely small.  A normal approximation such as `1-pnorm(722.5,mean=600,sd=sqrt(240))` would give `1.332268e-15` which is also extremely small: as Ross says, you are almost eight standard deviations above the mean.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  The ending value is a binomial distribution.  First calculate how many ups are required so you are up by 5%.  Note that the order of ups and downs don't matter to your final result, just the number.  Then calculate the chance that you have that many.

Comment: I did calculate that and figured out that i need the random variable X=> 723. However, when I used a cumulative density function for binomials on many online calculators from i = 723 to 1000, I would get 0 because the probability is very small. This made me think that my method was incorrect

Comment: @user43956:   I didn't check 723, but it looks about right. A good check is how many standard deviations you need to be above the mean.  If I recall correctly, the standard deviation is $\sqrt {npq} \approx 15$ (I used $p=.5, \sqrt {1000}\approx 30$ as I could do that easily), so you need to be 8 sd high which never happens.

Comment: Wouldn't the mean be np?

Comment: @user43956: no, the mean is $u^{np}d^{nq}$ because on average you have $np$ ups and $nq$ downs. The asymmetry in the ups and downs is very important.  What is the expected value of a single change?